# SOLVED-How do I fix error with access control in web.config file?

Tags: web-config, access-control

Im getting this error and I don´t know how to fix it.The site is live so therefor I don´t want to test a lot of stuff, breaking it wile testing.
I guess the problem is in my web.config file and that its related to the service worker that I use to cache files since that is using "fetch".

The error Im getting.

```
Fetch API cannot load https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?... due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

And the web.config file looks like this.

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="public, max-age=365000000" />
                   
    <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="['https://mydomain.se','http://dibspayment.eu','https://checkout.dibspayment.eu','https://www.google-analytics.com']" />-->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="'HEAD,OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="'X-Requested-With, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept, Authorization, Content-Length,Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Cache-Control'" />
                     
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

My service worker looks like this.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    self.skipWaiting() 
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v19').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/js/jquery.cookie.js',
        '/js/jquery.sumoselect.min.js',
        '/js/wookmark.min.js',
        '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js',
        '/js/exif/exif.min.js',
        '/js/exif/load-image.min.js',
        '/js/exif/load-image-scale.min.js',
        '/js/exif/load-image-orientation.min.js',
        '/fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.woff2',
        '/fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.woff',
        '/fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.ttf',
        '/fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.eot',
      ]);
       //caches.open(v2)
//.then( cache = cache.match('/js/v5/framework7.bundle.min.js'))
//.then( res =res.text())
//.then( js = console.log(js))
    })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if (event.request.clone().method === 'GET') {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open("v19").then(function (cache) {
        return fetch(event.request).then(function (res) {
        
          cache.put(event.request, res.clone());
          return res;
        })
      })
    )
  } else if (event.request.clone().method === 'POST') {
    // attempt to send request normally
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request.clone()).catch(function
    (error) {
      // only save post requests in browser, if an error occurs
      //savePostRequests(event.request.clone().url, form_data)
    }))
  }
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  var cacheKeeplist = ['v19'];

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList)  {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key)  {
        if (cacheKeeplist.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
});
```

How should I do with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin? I guess that´s where the problem is, or?
Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Solution:
Ok so I changed it to this so it is not caching google.analytis and the error went away.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

if (( event.request.url.indexOf( 'analytics' ) !== -1 ) || ( event.request.url.indexOf( 'checkout' ) !== -1 )){
            
}else{
      if (event.request.clone().method === 'GET') {
        event.respondWith(
          caches.open("v19").then(function (cache) {
            return fetch(event.request).then(function (res) {
            
              cache.put(event.request, res.clone());
              return res;
            })
          })
        )
      } else if (event.request.clone().method === 'POST') {
        // attempt to send request normally
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request.clone()).catch(function
        (error) {
          // only save post requests in browser, if an error occurs
          //savePostRequests(event.request.clone().url, form_data)
        }))
      }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the issue with yours `web.config`, but Google Analytics (GA) server's. So you have to adjust requests to meet GA requirements.

[image]

1. GA responses do not want to be cached (underlined in green). All transfer of statistics is done in the send request, the answer is only confirmation of delivery (the text like **1gfr**).
2. GA do not accept requests with credentials (underlined in red) because of:
      - presents of wildcard [* in Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411480/angular-a-wildcard-cannot-be-used-in-the-access-control-allow-origin-head) response header
      - absent of [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687313/what-exactly-does-the-access-control-allow-credentials-header-do/24689738#24689738) in responce header

Hence GA wait cross-origin requests with no credentials (no auth cookies should not be sent). The `feth()` uses `mode: 'cors', credentials: 'same-origin'` by [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) (send credentials only to same-origin requests), therefore all should be OK.

But if you still have got CORS error above, it means some browsers send credentials. Try to set `Request.credentials` to `"omit"` as [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) by Mozilla.

Or may be it's possible to exclude GA from caching and let process GA requests native way (GA natively  use `XMLHttpRequest` with `withCredentials = false` option, not `fetch()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot Granty, now I check if it is the analytics request and not caching it. I updated my question with the solution. Thanks again :-)