# Dynamic jQuery input refreshes the page because of error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser, preventdefault

I am making this input form through which users can add names of members in a team. I have four sets of input text fields. Initially, I let one of them be visible, and make the other three have `hidden` `display`s. Through javascript, I want the user to see a new set of these inputs by pressing the add member button. This works perfectly on my localhost. However, when I deploy it, the page reloads/refreshes itself whenever I press the add button. And in the console, it gives this error
`The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.`

```js
function add(){
    if($('#total_chq').val() < 4){
        var index = parseInt($('#total_chq').val()) + 1;
        $('#member_' + index).show();
        $('#total_chq').val(index);
    }
}
function remove(){
    var last_no = $('#total_chq').val();
    if(last_no > 1){
        $('#member_' + last_no).hide();
        $('#total_chq').val(last_no - 1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="member_container">
    <!-- first guy -->
    <div class="form-field">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="firstname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="lastname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second guy -->
    <div class="form-field" style="display: none;" id="member_2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="firstname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="lastname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- third guy -->
    <div class="form-field" style="display: none" id="member_3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="firstname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="lastname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fourth guy -->
    <div class="form-field" style="display: none;" id="member_4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="firstname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="lastname1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
<button class="btn btn-outline-none" onclick="add()">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Member
</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-none" onclick="remove()">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i> Remove Member
</button>
```

Comment: How is your function add() being called? I don't see it in your html. Anyway looks like you need to call event.preventDeault when adding since this looks like normal submit behaviouw of maybe a wrapper form element.

Comment: @Klaassiek hi  sorry, I just added the missing HTML.

Comment: It's not an error. And the refreshing has probably nothing to do with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094328/how-to-fix-content-security-policy-contains-an-invalid-source-error

Comment: @yochanansheinberger thank you for your suggestion! I checked that out but how do I prevent it from refreshing? Are you suggesting it is because of another problem?

Comment: Yes. BTW you have a typo in all the last name input elements `type="texc"`

Comment: Do you have more JS code which handles the inputs?

Comment: @yochanansheinberger no, but I am using flask to store these inputs into the database. Thanks for spotting the typo :D

Comment: It's a long shot, but try use `event.preventDefault()` as @klaassiek suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230992/discussion-between-yochanan-sheinberger-and-steven-oh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things might help. First make sure to use the `type` attribute and make sure to set it as `button`. As [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) suggests:

> Always specify the type attribute for the  element. Different browsers may use different default types for the  element.

If that doesn't do the trick, use `event.preventDefault()` in your `add` function. First add the event to the inline part:

```
<button onclick="add(event);" type="button">
```

Then adjust the first two lines of the add function, like so:

```
function add(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```