# Page on the macbook does not load

Tags: html, css, macos, web, safari

I am webdeveloper and my client has problem with his new website. He has Macbook PRO, Safari 15.0 and this 2 subpages are loading incomplete:

https://datalook.cz/nastroj/

https://datalook.cz/reporty/

on my Macbook PRO m1 is everything ok). There is also a video of page loading from the client:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FEj2xGtIQNWHcyPP1qpTTC3xJzBjwXLP/view

Does anyone know where the problem may be?

Thank you.

Comment: Open the console:)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that error in the console.

> [Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.

Check that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094328/how-to-fix-content-security-policy-contains-an-invalid-source-error) please.